# How to append to an interface{} in json file

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to append a map[string]interface{} to an existing map[string]interface{} in a json file.

Original json file:

```
{
   
    "frames": {
      "d_65541723636int": {
        "objectId": "d_65541723636"
      }
    }
 }
```

expect json file after append:

```
{
       
 "frames": {
    "d_65541723636int": {
        "objectId": "d_65541723636"
    }
    "anotherthing": {
        "objectId": "d_65541723636"
    }
 }
}
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Are you sure that's the result you are looking for?  The names within a JSON object should be unique.

Comment: use json.Marshal and json.Unmarshal, useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var m = make(map[string]interface{})
    sjson := `{   
    "frames": {
      "d_65541723636int": {
        "objectId": "d_65541723636"
      }
    }
 }`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(sjson), &m)
    m["anotherthing"] = make(map[string]interface{})
    m["anotherthing"].(map[string]interface{})["objectId"] = "d_65541723636"
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", m)
}
```